# How to print a lambda-function?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

I'm struggling with printing a simple lambda-function. I tried a variety of things but they all give errors. Any ideas?

See code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [18,28,29,32,35,36,37,37,39,40,42,42,46,48,54,56,57,61,61,62,63,65],
    "B":  [9,13,17,15,23,21,24,28,26,30,29,36,38,42,40,48,40,51,54,50,51,57]
})

a = lambda df: np.corrcoef(df[:,0], df[:,1])[0,1]

print(a(df)) # -> TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
print(a())   # -> TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'
print(a)     # -> prints the function but not the result and it's the result I want
```

Solution:

```
a = lambda df: np.corrcoef(df["A"], df["B"])[0,1]
a = lambda df: np.corrcoef(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1])[0,1]
print(a(df))
```

Comment: Read your error messages.

Comment: Not sure why you formulated your question this way. What you need to figure out is why your function is throwing a TypeError exception not how to print the function

Comment: Before you can print the result, you have to first be able to invoke it successfully, which so far you have not.  Try just `a(df)`, and debug that.  Worry about printing the result later, when you actually have a result.

Comment: All helpfull, now the lambda-function is used to set a parameter in a bootstrapping function from a bootstrapping-package I downloaded. That script works, so the lambda-function has to work as well...  So, why can't I print the result then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/10min.html) and read the error message carefully. The pandas dataframe slicing you're attempting is invalid (`df[:,0]` and `df[:,1]`). Try instead:

```
>>> a = lambda df: np.corrcoef(df["A"], df["B"])[0,1]
>>> print(a(df))
0.9744997251537248
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a solution. And if i don't know the header names it's as: a= lambda df: np.corrcoef(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1])[0,1]. That's solved then.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages are pretty explicit.

```
print(a(df)) # -> TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
# your function have an error, the [:, 0] item access is invalid

print(a())   # -> TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'
# you cannot call a function that expect an argument without argument
print(a)     # -> prints the function but not the result and it's the result I want
# you ask for printing a function, it prints a function
```

I think you did not get what a lambda function is.
It is an anonymous function, there is not point in affecting it.
This:

```
a = lambda df: np.corrcoef(df[:,0], df[:,1])[0,1]
```

Is exactly like this:

```
def a(df):
    return np.corrcoef(df[:,0], df[:,1])[0,1]
```